# Emulating the 'layout' functionality of Jade while using Mustache

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I setup node and express then integrated the mustache.js template by following the instructions on this page:

http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-express

So far so good, except I'm having a lot of trouble trying to setup mustache.js to have the same functionality as Jade's "layout". I'm basically trying to setup 1 master file to serve as a shell for my other pages similar to extending a template with Django.

Ex. The layout file could have this:

[html]

[title]my title[/title]

[body]{{content}}[/body]

[/html]

Where {{content}} gets replaced with the contents of a file which I would specify somehow in the route for that page.

I just have no idea how to set this up with express because I'm still a huge newbie with it and the way it's setup with Jade is automagical which seems to be specific to Jade only.

With Jade you just need to make a "layout.jade" file and have something like this as your route:

`app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.render('home', { title: 'My home page' }); });`

Then it magically adds the contents of home.jade into your layout.jade file wherever you specified the body!= body tag.

So yeah, how can I set something like that up with Mustache? If you know the answer please explain it step by step.

Comment: Found out a solution...
https://github.com/fat/stache/

Seems to work as intended. Maybe someone with more knowledge of this can check his code to make sure it's not adding a ton of overhead?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [stache](https://github.com/fat/stache/) renderer plugin for [docpad](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/)